# fes:DWithin throw parsing Error upon upgrade of geoserver from 2.13 to 2.18

Tags: geoserver, geotools, spatial-filter

We are using geoserver to do some wfs filtering.
It was ok until we switched from version 2.13.0 to 2.17.2 first, then up to 2.18.2 (because we hoped the pb would be solved with newer version).
Unfortunately, the filter "*fes:DWithin*" started to fail on parsingError with **NullPointerException** as soon as we started using 2.17+.

Our payload is generated by geotools. It looks like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wfs:GetFeature
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:myapp="myapp"
    xmlns:fes="http://www.opengis.net/fes/2.0"
    xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs/2.0"
    xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2"
    xmlns:ows="http://www.opengis.net/ows/1.1"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" outputFormat="JSON" resolve="none" resolveDepth="*" resolveTimeout="300" resultType="results" service="wfs" version="2.0.0">
    <wfs:Query srsName="http://www.opengis.net/gml/srs/epsg.xml#4326" typeNames="stg">
        <fes:Filter>
            <fes:And>
                <fes:Or>
                    <fes:Intersects>
                        <fes:ValueReference>sf:geom</fes:ValueReference>
                        <gml:MultiPoint srsDimension="2" srsName="http://www.opengis.net/gml/srs/epsg.xml#4326">
                            <gml:pointMember>
                                <gml:Point srsDimension="2" srsName="http://www.opengis.net/gml/srs/epsg.xml#4326">
                                    <gml:pos>-3.4611926 48.7367668</gml:pos>
                                </gml:Point>
                            </gml:pointMember>
                        </gml:MultiPoint>
                    </fes:Intersects>
                    <fes:Or>
                        <fes:DWithin>
                            <fes:ValueReference>sf:geom</fes:ValueReference>
                            <gml:Point srsDimension="2" srsName="http://www.opengis.net/gml/srs/epsg.xml#4326">
                                <gml:pos>-3.4611926 48.7367668</gml:pos>
                            </gml:Point>
                            <fes:Distance>1.0</fes:Distance>
                        </fes:DWithin>
                    </fes:Or>
                </fes:Or>
            </fes:And>
        </fes:Filter>
    </wfs:Query>
</wfs:GetFeature>
```

We tried with a [wfs:DWithin basic exemple](http://schemas.opengis.net/filter/2.0/examples/2.1.2/filter29.xml), and it keeps failing the same way (parsing error).

```
wfs_geoserver 2021-03-24T18:15:36:516+0100 access INFO: 10.0.1.81 - - "POST /geoserver/wfs HTTP/1.1" "-" "PostmanRuntime/7.6.0" 400 382 "http-nio-8080-exec-4" 165 -
wfs_geoserver     at org.geoserver.platform.AdvancedDispatchFilter.doFilter(AdvancedDispatchFilter.java:37)
wfs_geoserver     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
...
wfs_geoserver Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Parsing failed for DWithin: java.lang.NullPointerException
wfs_geoserver     at org.geotools.xsd.impl.ParseExecutor.visit(ParseExecutor.java:153)
wfs_geoserver 
...
wfs_geoserver Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
wfs_geoserver     at org.geotools.filter.v1_0.OGCDWithinBinding.parse(OGCDWithinBinding.java:82)
wfs_geoserver     at org.geotools.xsd.impl.ParseExecutor.visit(ParseExecutor.java:144)
wfs_geoserver     ... 118 more
```

Is there something wrong with our envelope?
And since we do not have control on the generation of the payload, is there a workaround?

**Some additionals informations based on comments/answers :**

- only the "DWithin" part triggers the pb. Removing the "intersects" part as well as the logical operators does not make it work.
- switching from DWithin do Within makes it work
- Adding spearfish (sf) namespace does not change the result

Comment: Does the filter work with just the Intersects part?

Comment: Yes, it does. Only the DWithin has a pb. Swiching from DWithin to Within does work (but is not what we look for)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This exception is caused by a [bug](https://osgeo-org.atlassian.net/browse/GEOT-6703) in Geotools 24.x. It's fixed in [release 25](https://github.com/geotools/geotools/commit/e2389fdfdae9f418576120516a8cb6094c9aed59#diff-500ab093d1965fa078c1303b45d4655739f3dbe03b415aae77ad8b15c5697598)

To apply this correction to the next release of Geoserver [2.18.3](https://github.com/geoserver/geoserver/wiki/Release-Schedule), you need to backport this fix on geotools 24.X

Regards,

Comment: We tried geoserver 2.19 (including geotools 25.x) and it works. We we'll submit the backport. Thanks @eropartz

Answer (score 1):

I've just tested with 2.18.1 and 2.19.0 and once I change the layer to `sf:bugsites` and the geometry to `sf:the_geom` and add in the reference to `sf` (`xmlns:sf="http://www.openplans.org/spearfish"`) to the XML it works (well it returns an empty response).

So, I suspect that you need the declaration of the `sf` namespace you refer to in the geometry names or to change that to match your actual namespace (myapp?) - you probably also need the namespace in your `typeNames` element.

Comment: Ian, I am not sure I understand your changes : I understand the namespace declaration (added), but about the layer and the geom : you mean in something like "typeNames='sf:bugsites'" ?
Anyway, I can't have your solution work. Thus, I may have misunderstand some part. Can you provide the payload you used?

Comment: The sf namespace works with Intersects so how could it be a problem with DWithin? Could there be something going on with the units? Undefined 1.0 means probably one degree.

Comment: can you generate a query that fails using one of the standard datasets so I can test it without needing to make changes?